# Unidentified devices after reinstallation of Windows7

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

I re-installed Windows 7 and I currently have 2 `Base System Devices` with a yellow exclamation which means it's unrecognized and the drivers for it are missing.

Windows update has been unable to find the missing drivers for the device and I can't figure out what the device could be.

I have a Sony vaio VPCEB44EN laptop. What could the `Base System Device` be?

Comment: OP has 2 unidentified / unrecognized devices in the device manager.

Comment: Drivers for hardware (what else) for me it was a part of a raid card, that was not really important to operation.  Did you hop onto the sony site and track down any chipset (type) drivers for your specific model of computer?  Check for other drivers they supply FOR that specific computers specific hardware, install of it what you need, and what may be required for proper operation.  Windows does not (at all) have every driver for every device in the system or in the updates for the system.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading the chipset driver to your computer, often this resolves issuse like these where Windows isnt quite aware of what the unindentified devices are.

You can find your drivers here http://www.sony.co.in/support/download/419265/product/vpceb44en

Just download the chipset driver and install it, let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the device-id of the device and enter it here:

http://devid.info/

If you have problems finding the device-id in the device-manager you might want to try the tool of devid:

http://devid.info/en/page/devidinstaller

A similar tool is http://driveridentifier.com/